# ASP.NET Core 3 app not refreshing HTML/CSS changes in browser

Tags: google-chrome, iis, iis-express, page-refresh, asp.net-core-3.0

I have issues when saving HTML/CSS files, these are not being shown when I refresh the page, doesn't matter what browser I try; I have tried disabling cache in the Network tab in google chrome but still not working, I even tried setting up my site with local IIS instead of using IIS Express but still not refreshing my changes, even when I do Empty cache and Hard Reload in chrome, the changes only are shown when I re-launch the application. I don't know what else I can try, any suggestions? thanks in advance!

Comment: Make your answer below and accept it please.

Comment: Done, but can't accept my own answers

Comment: I don't know the latest rules, but you should be able to accept it in a few hours.

Answer (score 3):

In NET Core 3 we need to install this package, following this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio and activate the recompilation of views in 3.0

Comment: Note that you'll still need to refresh the page in the browser